# SV agreement: does the second verb in the clause after "and", sharing the same subject as the verb in the first clause, use the same sing./plr. form?

Tags: exam-questions, verb-agreement

The sentence is:

> "The machine's remote-control unit puts you in charge of starting and stopping your workout and ____ the speed and direction of the oncoming tennis balls."

The question is from a cloze test and it has 4 choices:

> 1. let you adjust
> 2. lets you adjust
> 3. let you to adjust
> 4. become more skilled

I'm choosing between 1 and 2. Now if I think grammatically I would choose 2, but somehow it doesn't seem to sound right for me. Is my intuition bad or is it really wrong?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. 2 seems correct to me. This would be a much harder question if "letting" was one of the options, although "putting you in charge of letting you adjust" is pretty horrible.

Comment: Mai Mee, did you notice that whatever it means, *The machine's remote-control unit puts you in charge of starting and stopping your workout and ____ the speed and direction of the oncoming tennis balls* will always make native English speakers hesitate? It's unidiomatic, at best.

The most obvious solution would be *and controlling the speed* but everything would still be questionable.